# Generate and store electronic (digital) signatures

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, digital-signature, electronic-signature

I have a requirement for the web service I'm working on currently - users of the application can create contracts between them (downloadable via PDF) and **sign these contracts digitally on the app**.

At first I was searching for third-party API solutions that will help me with storing signatures and sign documents between users. But as I see such solutions like [Docusign](https://www.docusign.com/) and [Hellosign](https://www.hellosign.com/) concentrate on a providing a bit different kind of service. Then I've read an article on [*difference between Digital and Electronic signature*](http://www.arx.com/learn/about-digital-signature/digital-vs-electronic/) but I'm not yet sure what is the best kind of signature for the app.

What I'm looking for is a secure way to sign a pdf contract file for both users inside my application. The common app flow looks like that:

- user1 sends contract information on our server
- user2 sends contract information on our server
- server generates pdf file base on provided information, file can be previewed on the web/mobile client
- user1 and user2 can sign document on the web/mobile client (use some API here for digital/electronic signature? store signatures in our database?)
- after document is signed no changes can be made
- user1 can have several contracts so it will be handy to use his existing signature on the next docs

My main question here is it worth looking for third-party APIs or it will be safe enough to develop our own sign system? There are such open-source projects as https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad which can be used to generating signature image. Or create some kind of signature key to mimic digital signature and store inside app's database?

Any input will be highly appreciated as I'm new on this topic. Thanks!

P.S. Maybe [CoSign](http://developer.arx.com/resources/documentation/) can be an option but its' developer docs is offline for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to deliver a solid experience with legally binding contracts than your solution would probably be good enough to compete with the likes of Docusign etc... However, many companies would not want to hand roll a custom signing process which also add's legal complications if you expect this contract to offer something a little more substantial than a terms of service being checked.

Basically, Docusign has spent a considerable amount of wealth building, spreading and lobbying their product, to the point where it is now used by major fortune 500 companies for very important transactions which include insurance, deeds and medical documents.

I guess my point is, if you were going to go through all of that effort, why not have that be the product you're trying to build?  To me, especially with most products I tend to build, it's not worth the effort and easier to pay a tried and true company like Docusign, but everybody's situation is different.

Comment: Actually I would like to pay Docusign but for now I couldn't find any valuable developer documentation on their site that will help me to create my product. What I need from 3rd party API is to accept document through API that will be signed by 2 other people that are not users of Docusign. I don't want Docusign to treat me like a contract holder.

Comment: Users of your product to not need to be users of docusign in order to sign a docusign form.  Docusign allows for signing of forms by two or more people as well.  Basically you generate your form with Docusign through your account and then use the api to build a list of signers and send the signers the email link they need to click on to sign the document (this link will be on docusigns website).  then you need to store the signed document on your end once the transaction is completed.  Docusign can send you an event that both signatures have been applied.

Comment: Firstly is form the same document template? I need to send pdf files which are contracts between two users and can be different. Secondly I would like to make signing process on my app, some kind of embedding then?

Comment: 1.  yes they can sign the same document, there can be two signature spots differentiated by recipient.  2.  sorry I'm not sure if you can embed the signing process in your app.  Typically from what I've seen, the signing process takes place on docusign's site, but you can customize it to include your logo and colors etc...

Comment: Thanks, for your input, I will try to search their API, but needless to say that user experience on their app is bad. Another point is that Advanced plan costs 300$ and allows only *Send documents for signature: 100/Month* which is low rate for our app.